# Using Nextjs components in a package consumed by a nextjs application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Nextjs website that consumes a package with a set of react components. This package has nextjs installed too but its extremely heavy and only used for next links. I am working on removing nextjs from the package.

Is there a way I can use the next link component in the package without adding next as a dependency. It seems strange to add it in both. I would like to know the recommended approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be an issue. Nextjs should only get installed once. All new installations with override any previous installation. To avoid conflicts, just make sure your project and package have the same versions of react.